# virtual machine query?

Tags: linux, vmware, vmware-player

hi i have installed ubuntu 10.4 as guest OS on vmware and windows xp is my host.
now i want do know does vmware give a new ip address to the linux os.. if yes how do i get that ip address

Comment: Check the address with `ifconfig eth0`. Shouldn't this belong to superuser.com?

Answer (score 0):

yes it should, try running ifconfig from the console.

Hope this helps,

Jason.

Comment: ya that gives me the same ip address as i get from my windows xp

Comment: Have a look at the DHCP Server configuration, you can find this on your Windows host under:

Start -> All Programs -> VMWare -> VMWare Server -> Manage Virtual Networks

Might be worth reviewing the network mode, whether it is using Nat etc.  I don't have it installed at the moment so sorry if this isn't as clear as I'd hope!